# Is a large number of grid columns/rows a performance concern?

Tags: css, performance, css-grid

There is a grid with many small rows and columns, something like this:

[image]

Items will be placed inside it, for example:

[image]

Grid is created with something like:

```
grid-template-rows: repeat(auto-fill, 10px);
grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, 10px);
```

- Width of the grid can be as wide as browser window, say 2000px.
- Height can be a multiple screens, say 10000px.
- Tracks are not visible to the user, above images are just to demonstrate how CSS Grid layout looks.
- There can be hundreds of "items" (grey areas on above image), each occupying some number of cells (it can be 1x1 item, and it can be 60x40 item)

**Questions**

- Is this a performance concern? Is it expensive for browsers to generate grid with a few hundred columns and a few thousand rows?
- If yes, is there a way to optimize `repeat(auto-fill, 10px)`? Maybe  percentages should be used instead (`repeat(auto-fill, 1%))`, or something instead of `auto-fill`?

Or it's better doing this via JavaScript (height to container, left/top to items)?

Comment: In chrome there is a limiation of the number of rows (related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/54956609/8620333)

Comment: If this will only be a visual thing, you can probably consider better technique like canvas, background, etc where you will need few elements

Comment: Css grid is a very efficient way to do this kind of operation. It will have a small footprint and will still be far superior to other options including javascript. Why don't you just knock it up and see how it performs? It's not that big of an operation.

Comment: Dayum, I wish we could have opinion- and experience-based Q&A about such topics, it's really fascinating.