# What is the maximum amount of columns and/or rows in a css grid

Tags: css-grid

When dynamically filling css grid columns I recently noticed that after column 1000 the remainder seems to be filled in the row direction. See the example below. This leads me to the question:

**Is there a maximum amount of rows and/or columns when using CSS grid?**

Suggestions of how to get the remainder (from 1001 on) in the next columns are welcome, but are not the core of this question.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The CSS grid seems to have a different column/row limit depending on the browser.

For chrome the limit seems to be 1,000x1,000 as explained [here in the answer of Bludev](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47218341/css-grid-layout-in-chrome-seems-not-to-work-properly-with-more-than-1000-rows)

For firefox the limit seems to be 10,000x10,000, but I can't remember exactly where i read this.